# Remove linear trend from data

Tags: fitting, performance-tuning

I have a large data set with 150k lines and two data columns. I noticed that there is a linear trend, which I want to remove. So, I do the following:

First, fit with a linear model:

```
model = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

then, I subtract the fit from the data:

```
data1 = data;
data1[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] - model[data[[All, 1]]] + model[0];
```

This, however, takes unacceptable amount of time. Is there any way I can speed things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to remove the linear trend. Just use `Fit`, and this is also easy to understand.(And a little faster than Mr Alpha's on my computer.)

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 50], {150000, 2}] + Range[150000];
AbsoluteTiming[
  f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x}, x];
  ans=Transpose@{data[[;; , 1]], data[[;; , 2]] - f@data[[;; , 1]]};]
(*==>{0.047003, Null}*)
```

Mr Alpha's code

```
AbsoluteTiming[{a, b} = 
  LeastSquares[DesignMatrix[data, x, x], data[[All, 2]]];
  data1 = Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], 
  data[[All, 2]] - (a + b*data[[All, 1]])};]
(*==>{0.054003, Null}*)
```

Comment: Not really much of a difference in timing, which is expected, since both use least-squares methods underneath. On the other hand, since only the coefficients are wanted, `FindFit[]` is more expedient than `Fit[]` since the former yields the coefficients themselves, and the latter yields a function that you still have to extract coefficients from.

Comment: @J.M. I'm not familiar with the methods underneath. Well, I think if dealing with more complex form, using my code, I don't need to construct the function manually in the end. And apply the fitted function to the data seems most natural to me.

Comment: In that case, you can skip the use of `f`: `Function[x, Fit[data, {1, x}, x] // Evaluate] @ data[[;; , 1]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes. From the other side, this one-line-code makes it slightly difficult to understand. (Just a matter of personal taste:)

Comment: I like this solution the most, because it is faster and easier to understand than the others. PS. I also think FindFit is better.

Comment: @phidelio I'm not familiar with the algorithm underneath the fit family. Could you explain why you prefer `FindFit`?Thank you for adopting my answer BTW:) This is my first answer adopted on SE.

Answer (score 7):

If all you want is to remove a linear trend from the data you don't need all the fancy statistics done by `LinearModelFit` and a faster alternative is to just use `LeastSquares` and then use the resulting parameters to remove the trend from the data.

```
(*Generate 150k datapoints with a linear trend*)
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 50], {150000, 2}] + 
   Range[150000];

(*The LinearModelFit version*)
AbsoluteTiming[
 model = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
 data1 = data;
 data1[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] - model /@ data[[All, 1]] + model[0];
 ]

(*==> {30.053463, Null} *)

(*Faster alternative*)
AbsoluteTiming[{a, b} = 
  LeastSquares[DesignMatrix[data, x, x], data[[All, 2]]];
 data1 = Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], 
    data[[All, 2]] - (a + b*data[[All, 1]])};
 ]

(*==> {0.044045, Null} *)
```

It is around 700 times faster on my machine.

Comment: wow, that is a lot faster. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using is incorrect.  Try `model[{1,2,3}]` and notice that it can't be applied to a list.  Just change `model[data[[All,1]]]` to `model /@ data[[All,1]]`.

This will finish in time, but it won't be fast at all (I do not know why).

This will be much faster (in place of `model /@ data[[All,1]]`):

```
model["BestFit"] /. x -> data[[All, 1]]
```

Comment: I do wonder why something as simple as `model["BestFit"]` takes a noticeable amount of time, though.  It should be instantaneous.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to note one thing. For small list `model["BestFit"] /. x -> data[[All, 1]]` indeed gives faster results. However, for my dataset, I had to abort, because after 5 mins it wasn`t ready and had consumed 15 GB RAM. On the other hand `model /@ data[[All,1]]` took only 110 sec and negligible amount of RAM

Answer (score 1):

If one absolutely insists on using `LinearModelFit[]` for linear detrending:

```
model = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
trendFree = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], model["FitResiduals"] + model[0]}];
```

Otherwise, we can do something quite similar to Mr. Alpha's procedure:

```
b = Last[LeastSquares[DesignMatrix[data, x, x], data[[All, 2]]]];
trendFree = data.{{1, -b}, {0, 1}};
```

Comment: No, I don't insist on `LinearModelFit[]`. It was the first command google gave me for fitting linear functions

Comment: Hi, @phidelio. That sentence was more figurative than literal; I meant that if one is going to be using that function for detrending and other purposes besides, then at least the detrending part is easy.

Comment: Useful. Been using LinearModelFit forever without concerns for performance.